# Factorise $a^m + 1$

Tags: factoring

I thought of maybe splitting it up: $$(a^m + 1)(a^{m-1} - \ldots - a^1 + 1).$$

But this method came to no avail as I had some extra terms left behind. We know nothing about $a$ or $m$ beforehand (i.e. prime or not, etc.).

Comment: [This](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-solve-the-equation-z-n-+-1-0-for-n-geq-2) might help you?

Comment: @JohnDoe: No, that is a completely different question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The roots can be use to factorise it, and the roots are the $\text{m}^\text{th}\text{ roots of }-1$. I don't know if this is what OP intended however.

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ is *not* a power of $2$, then write $m=st$ with $s\ge 3$ odd. Then
$$ a^m+1 = (a^t+1)(a^{(s-1)t}-a^{(s-2)t}+a^{(s-3)t}-\cdots + 1) $$

This doesn't work when $m$ is a power of $2$. Then it is possible that $a^m+1$ is prime, as it is for $2^1+1, 2^2+1, 2^4+1, 2^8+1$, and $2^{16}+1$. These are the only *known* exceptions for $a=2$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_primes for other $a$s.

Comment: and if m is a power of 2?

Comment: @MargaretM: That's what the second paragraph of the answer discusses. Since the number is sometimes prime in that case (and it is not even _known_ whether there are Fermat primes beyond the first five) you shouldn't hope for any generally applicable strategy there.